# woocommerce_thankyou get's called 4 times

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using woocommerce_thankyou to execute an action on checkout. However, in a simple test, if I set the action and just "echo 'Test';" it happens 4 times.
This is the code

```
class OrderController 
{ 
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($this, 'orderSubmit')); 
    } 

    function orderSubmit() 
    { 
        global $woocommerce;
        echo "test"; // happens 4 times 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I know this sucks. But the answer to this is that it magically worked itself out. Wish I could provide an answer to it, but I believe it may have had to do with our AutoLoader. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue earlier today.

I went into server file viewer (or local host) and went to wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout

Inside the checkout folder there is a php file called thankyou.php.

Around line 65 or so there will be code that says

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou' . $order->payment_method, $order->id ); ?>
```

Or something similiar

The issue in mine is that it had 2 of these action executions.

Get rid of all them except one and this should fix your problem.

Be sure to test your woocommerce afterwards to ensure you didn't delete the wrong one

Comment: This helped me a lot ! Thanks so much ! This save my life !

Now i see the woocommerce_thankyou must include an _ID so i can identify from which plugin came the payment option.